# Why I can't open and read the file on python in powershell?

Tags: python, powershell

**I'm pretty sure I got the ex15_sample.txt in mystuff filefolder!**

Here is the error I encounter:
[image: the powershell]

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ex15_sample.txt'
```

That's my code

```
from sys import argv   

script, filename = argv   

txt = open(filename)       
print "Here's your file %r:" % filename   
print txt.read()                     
print "Type the filename again:"
file_again = raw_input("> ")         

txt_again = open(file_again)           

print txt_again.read()          `
```

Comment: What error/s do you encounter?

Comment: Maybe `python.exe` starts with a different working directory. What is the output of `os.getcwd()`?

Comment: what is the output of dir command?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
    import os
    __location__ = os.path.realpath(
    os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__)))

    file_name = raw_input("type the file name")
    txt = open(os.path.join(__location__, filename))
    print txt.read()
```